# Realm subquery with List count in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, realm

I have

```
class Car : Object
{
     let queries : List<QueryModel> = List<QueryModel>()
}
```

and

```
class QueryModel : Object
{
    let location : String = ""
}
```

Now how do I write that NSPredicate to fetch just that cars which have queries with location equal to 'London'?

p.s. It's a known fact that things like @count do not work on Swift List class...

p.p.s. I need it as a predicate because this is the only way RBQFetchedResultsController knows how to do it's job.

How I thought it could've been written was something like `NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(queries, $query, $query.location == %@)", 'London')`. But nothing like this ever passes Realm's predicate validation :)

Comment: Are you sure about @count - I understand it works from version 0.96.

Comment: From what I understood, it most probably works, but just on ObjC stuff. It does not work on List which is the Swift equivalent of Realm collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
NSPredicate(format: "ANY queries.location = %@", locationString)
```

If you want to add other filtering, you can create other NSPredicate and then use

```
NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [pred1, pred2])
```

to combine the filters.

Now, if you want to filter cars, you have to prepare a

```
let request = FetchRequest<Car>(realm: realm, predicate: predicate)
```

then you can use RBQFetchedResultsController to execute the request.

Comment: I didn't test the Compound myself but I read it was also working with Realm. http://qiita.com/yusuga/items/add6f9e290b92f42104a (in japanese though sorry) I also read that a NSCompoundPredicate without subpredicates always evaluates to true but I don't think it's even relevant here. In your specific case, You only need 1 NSPredicate apparently. If you can, give it a try though. Just to be 100% sure about the NSCompoundPredicate works fine too. you can maybe combine 2 predicate with NSPredicate(format: "%K contains[c] %@", "Car.location", "on") and "Lon"

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it complains. Anyways, the problem here is your first predicate would still have to check for "count" property which is not set on a Obj.C. instance and thus can't be found.

Comment: It's not just that. The keypath is rather car.queries[index].location

Comment: Compound predicates are supported by Realm. @Fawkes: From my understanding @Mikael's proposal is what you want. If you use `ANY`, I don't see how you would need `@count`.

Comment: Ah, yes. It was about block predicates. I'm just wrapping my head around Realm the whole night. I'll check the solution, hopefully ANY does not encounter the same problem as @count.